# How to check if a certain relationship goes both ways on Memgraph?

Tags: cypher, memgraphdb, opencypher

I have a dataset in `Memgraph` and I'm trying to check if a certain relationship goes both ways.

But I'm either getting a failed query or wrong results.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query below avoids creating a cartesian product.

```
MATCH (p1)-[:FOO]->(p2)-[:FOO]->(p1)
WHERE ID(p1) <= ID(p2)
RETURN DISTINCT p1, p2
```

It also enforces an ordering on the native IDs of the returned `p1` and `p2` so that the same pair of nodes is not returned twice as `p1`/`p2` and also `p2`/`p1`
-- *unless* the same pair has more than two such relationships, in which case the same pair can still show up multiple times; let's call this `Caveat #1`. Also, if a node has self-relationships in both directions, it would show up multiple times in the result -- `Caveat #2`.

To address Caveats #1 and #2, we eliminate duplicate results by returning `DISTINCT` `p1`/`p2` pairs.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly what your issue is, this is my idea of the solution:

Let's say we have two nodes created, `p1` and `p2`, both with labels `Person` and relationship `CONNECTED_TO` between them. The following query will check if the person `p1` is connected to the person `p2` and vice versa:

```
MATCH (p1), (p2)
WHERE exists((p1)-[:CONNECTED_TO]->(p2)) AND
      exists((p2)-[:CONNECTED_TO]->(p1))
RETURN p1, p2
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This query creates a cartesian product and will be very slow.